# How to correctly hook CIDRAM to OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

Due to an growing invasion of [registration bots](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/115694) on an [OpenCart](https://github.com/opencart/opencart) website, I have decided to install [CIDRAM](https://github.com/CIDRAM/CIDRAM) which seems to be a robust solution to try reducing this kind of nuisance.

I though I have implemented the system correctly as `log` files were effectively created and gave a list of blocked IPs. But actually, I realized that CIDRAM wasn't properly "hooked" to OpenCart: indeed, since it has been installed, some manipulations aren't possible anymore because of the following error:

```php
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: 
unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I must have rummaged about the causes of such an error which isn't totally unknown: [maintenance mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29790755/4094098), [configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420093/4094098), [user API issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425318/4094098), etc. I have tested various of these known possible origins without success, when I found the [following advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29611996/4094098) in a checklist:

> Check if you have added any `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` into an if block to reject ips on purpose.

At this point, I have to consider that the recent installation of CIDRAM can be the main cause of this error: I removed the "hook" that I had manually added in the main `index.php` (before requiring [vQMOD](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod)) and it resolved the error.

```php
// OpenCart Configuration
if (is_file('config.php')) {
    require_once('config.php');
}
// OpenCart Install
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: install/index.php');
    exit;
}
// CIDRAM Hook
require './cidram/loader.php';
// VirtualQMOD
require_once('./vqmod/vqmod.php');
VQMod::bootup();
```

However, I would still like to be able to properly install CIDRAM in order to fully test its features (and I have of course [first ask the maintainers](https://github.com/CIDRAM/CIDRAM/issues/185) if they know a way to do it).

Thus, the question is now how to correctly "hook" CIDRAM to OpenCart without causing this `json` errors? Is it appropriate to hook in an other page than `index.php` or is it practicable to use a specific position in this main page?

Comment: When you say "hook into" OpenCart what is it that you're trying to do? Can you share some of the code that generates this error?

Comment: I talk about "hook" because it's the term used in [the documentation (Section 2, item 5)](https://github.com/CIDRAM/Docs/blob/master/readme.en.md#SECTION2). I wasn't sure if this was the code that was generating this error (hence my queries) and [it looks like it wasn't](https://github.com/CIDRAM/CIDRAM/issues/185#issuecomment-662429527). I add a code piece to make my initial post more explicit.

Comment: Oh okay, I see the term "hook" used more in Wordpress development than OpenCart! Do the logs in `/system/storage/logs/error.log` provide anything useful?

Comment: The native `error.log` was not really helpful, but [the CIDRAM one seems to have revealed the reason for the problem](https://github.com/CIDRAM/CIDRAM/issues/185#issuecomment-662429527). I'll post an answer to my own question when I'm sure everything is working fine. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve this issue! Is there any chance you'd be willing to create a "how to" article somewhere? I'm sure the community would appreciate that.